# Generate a big random float jquery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, floating-point

I need to generate a 12 digit and 13 decimals float value like this:

```
123438767411.238792938
```

How can I do that in Javascript/Jquery? Is it possible to generate this code using JavaScript?

I was trying like this:

```
v1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000000000)+1);
v2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*100000000)+1);
v = v1.toString() + "." + v2.toString();
```

But this is not working!

Comment: *"..is not working!"* is not a useful problem statement. What happens, how does it differ from what you expect, etc.

Comment: @A. Wolff: Isn't it possible to do using jquery only. I want this code for testing some scripts on server side. I can't insert third party plugins there!

Comment: @A.Wolff: You can have a whole number with more than 12 digits in JavaScript. JavaScript's numbers are double-precision IEEE-754 values. Their range is **huge**, and they have ~15 digits of precision. 123456789123, for instance, is a valid JavaScript number.

Comment: @LaxmikantGurnalkar you should use string then, not number

Comment: I'm doing same if you look at last line of code. Thanks

Comment: @LaxmikantGurnalkar But then where is your issue??? Looks fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/QtSRN/

Comment: @A.Wolff: It was returning 10 integers only. I think I was doing something wrong there. Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: also note if `1` is added to it, then the integer part can become 13 digits (although the chance is small)

Comment: Math.random().toString().substring(2,14)+ Math.random().toString().substring(1,15);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(assuming you mean in the form of a string, not as a number, because IEEE 754 can't have that many significant digits)

must the integer part be 12 digits or can it be 1 or 123?  If it can be 12 digits or shorter, then it can be

```
(Math.floor (Math.random() * Math.pow(10,12)) 
    + (Math.floor (Math.random() * Math.pow(10,13)) 
      / Math.pow(10,13)).toString().substring(1))
```

---

note that the above could have an issue when the decimal part turns out to be `0`, although the chance is really small. (then the `.0` part is gone, although we can use a conditional to add it when it is so).  Or we can treat the decimal part `123` not as `.0000000000123` but as `.123` and use:

```
(Math.floor (Math.random() * Math.pow(10,12)) 
    + "." + Math.floor (Math.random() * Math.pow(10,13)))
```

But it depends whether we care about `123` becoming `.123` and `1230` also becoming `.1230` because if we do care about it, we can say `.123` is the same as `.1230`.

Also, if we want to have the form such as `000042987017.0790946977900` as well, so that it is always 12 digit integer and 13 digit decimal, then either we can do zero padding or use something like this:

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/jL4t4/1/

```
var i, s = "";

for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    s += (i === 12) ? "." : Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}
```